# Number of HTTP Connections made by Android Application

Tags: android, http

How to calculate number of HTTP connections made by application, also concurrent connections made by app.. Is there any tool to calculate number of connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can not find the number of connections made,

Check this out,

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html